# How to implement multiple if clauses using logical operator in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, select, where-clause

I have 3 tables and I have to check the count for certain records as per below condition.

```
IF

count(T1DM DX = 0) & COUNT (T2DM DX = 0) & COUNT (T2DM MEDS >= 1) & COUNT(ABC > 6.5 OR DEF > 11.1 OR GHI > 7) >= 1 THEN "CASE"

ELSE

DO NOTHING

**OR** 

IF

count(T1DM DX = 0) & COUNT (T2DM DX >=1) & COUNT (T1DM MEDS = 0) & COUNT (T2DM MEDS = 0) & COUNT(ABC > 6.5 OR DEF > 11.1 OR GHI > 7) >= 1 THEN "CASE"

ELSE

DO NOTHING
```

My create table statements are given below

```
CREATE TABLE DX(
   DX_id  serial Primary Key
   person_id NOT NULL,
   condition_name VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   cond_id VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   condition_start_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   condition_end_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE RX(
   RX_id serial Primary Key
   person_id NOT NULL,
   presciption_name VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   presc_id VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   pres_start_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   pres_end_date TIMESTAMP 
);


CREATE TABLE Lab(
   Lab_id serial Primary Key
   person_id NOT NULL,
   Test_name VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   Test_id VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   Test_start_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   Test_value FLOAT
);
```

This is what I tried

```
IF ((select count(*) from public.DX where cond_id = 21) == 0 AND (select count(*) from public.DX where cond_id = 23) == 0 AND (select count(*) from public.RX where presc_id = 33) >=1
                                 AND (select count(*) from (select * from public.Lab where test_id in (41,42,43)) where test_value > 6.5)) THEN "FOUND"
ELSE
     DO NOTHING
```

But this throws error. Can anyone help me to implement multiple if clause with AND/OR logical operators in between them?

**Points to Note**

1) DX table can have multiple conditions. Based on the flowchart we need to look for T1DM and T2DM. We can identify them using cond_ids (T1DM - 21, T2DM - 23)

2) RX table can have multiple prescription of drugs. Based on flowchart we need to look for T1DM meds and T2DM meds. We can identify them using presc_ids (T1DM meds- 31, T2DM meds - 33)

3) Lab table can have multiple measurement/test results. Based on flowchart, abnormal lab is defined by threshold violation for any one of 3 measurements listed below.

```
 a) Three measurements - ABC, DEF, GHI. Test_ids for these three are 41,42,43
 b) ABC > 6.5
 c) DEF > 11.1
 d) GHI > 7
```

Comment: Compare your unclear fragments of presentation to [the apparent source of the diagram for this from your deleted earlier question about this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/gap/cgi-bin/document.cgi?study_id=phs000888.v1.p1&phv=226005&phd=4998&pha=&pht=4678&phvf=&phdf=&phaf=&phtf=&dssp=1&consent=&temp=1#fig1): "**Algorithm 1** T2DM case selection algorithm. This algorithm takes a patient-
level record (pt) as an argument, and returns the patient's case status
({CASE; UNKNOWN}) as result." Etc.

Comment: What does "throws error" mean? When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation.

Comment: I have already given the code that I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write this using `CASE` expressions along with exists logic:

```
CASE WHEN
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public.DX WHERE cond_id IN (21, 23)) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public.DX WHERE presc_id = 33) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public.Lab WHERE test_id IN (41,42,43) AND test_value > 6.5)
     THEN 'FOUND' END;
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the response. Upvoted. Will update in a few hours. But may I know what does 'select 1 from table' do?.  Couldn't try as I am traveling

Comment: @TheGreat . . . `EXISTS` only cares if the subquery returns at least one row; it doesn't care what the columns are on that row.  `1` is probably the simplest expression to type.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for that, and I'm on a cell phone at the moment.  Side note: Postgres doesn't really care what follows `EXISTS`, and even `NULL` (or nothing at all) can follow.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen - I am trying something like this `select case when exists (SELECT distinct c_id 
  FROM table_1 m
  JOIN dum_cts on (m.drcpt_id = dcpt_id and dcode_id in(3))) THEN "found"
  end from main_table`;

Comment: I am trying to select `c_id` records from main_table. `c_id` is got from table_1. Let's say `main_table` has 30 records and table_1 has 100 unique c_id. So i am expecting `main_table` to return 20 records because there are 20 common c_ids between both.